# Организация локального кэша для загрузки и обработки аудиофайлов на флексе\флеше

Tags: flash, аудио, apache-flex, storage

Разрабатываем приложение для веб-браузера флеше\флексе которое должно загружать с сервера большие аудиотреки и редактировать их (то есть клиентская часть)- аналог [Myna](http://advanced.aviary.com/tools/audio-editor) 
Встал вопрос, а как правильно и при помощи чего организовать кэш данных на клиенте (я даже не рассматриваю пока вопрос долговременного хранения) - получается сам кэш у флэша\флекса маленький. а нам нужна такая схема :
1 загрузили несколько треков с сервера в кэш
2 осуществили его редактирование на флеше
3 отдали результат серверу

Как варианты пока рассматриваем использование Shared Objects или appcache
возможно существуют элегантные и быстрые решения данного вопроса

**UPD:**
Переформулируем чуть вопрос - куда загружать-то? И где хранить во время работы? А хранить на клиенте таки-да, нужно, т.к с момента последнего изменения он мог ничего не сделать со своим файлом. Смысл лить то же самое. Критичный вопрос - куда флешу складывать временную информацию?

Comment: в вашей схеме не усматриваю жесткой необходимости хранить что то на клиенте

- загрузили
- отредактировали
- отправили на сервер

Comment: Вот я бы точно не стал ничего хранить из аудио на клиенте, на клиент закидываем только превьюшки (96-128кбит/мп3), которые сидят на треках, а все изменения и эффекты храним в виде данных (наборов операций, эффектов, действий), можно в куках, размер там уже будет не большой, можно на сервере, не суть. Полноценный полно-битрейтный файл давать сохранять отдельно при финальном экспорте проекта.

Comment: у нас небольшое недопонимание - я хочу хранить файлы на время обработки - как и при помощи чего мне это сделать?

Comment: если у вас браузерный клиент, то ни о каких файлах речь идти не может, только данные в памяти, runtime данные

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html